# "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" when using glutSwapBuffers() function

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, linker, glut

I am in the middle of writing a display function for the window in my OpenGL program. My function looks like this:

```
void window::display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Loop to draw all particles here
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

However, when I compile my program I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glutSwapBuffers", referenced from:
      window::display() in window.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already gotten this error for using glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) and was able to fix it by adding the -framework OpenGL flag when compiling. This issue is confusing me because glutSwapBuffers() is a GLUT thing, not an OpenGL thing so I don't know if I could fix it the same way or even how I would do that. Some additional info that may be useful: I am on Mac OSX 10.9.4, I have included "OpenGL/gl.h", "OpenGL/glu.h", and "GLUT/glut.h" in all files that require them, and my makefile looks like this...

```
COMPILECPP  = g++ -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -framework OpenGL -std=c++11
CPPSOURCE   = window.cpp main.cpp
EXECBIN     = psys
OBJECTS     = ${CPPSOURCE:.cpp=.o}

all : ${EXECBIN}

${EXECBIN} : ${OBJECTS}
    ${COMPILECPP} -o $@ ${OBJECTS}

%.o : %.cpp
    ${COMPILECPP} -c $<
```

Comment: You need to link against GLUT to get its symbols. Note that this is a linker issue, and has nothing whatsoever to do with `#include` statements.

Comment: [Reading material about linker unresolved symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465)

Comment: Did you installed the headers for 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @Braiam This is a linker issue, it has nothing to do with headers.